# Как сделать все элементы одинаковой высоты?

Tags: html, css, jquery

Как сделать все элементы одинаковой высоты, не задавая фиксированную высоту?

```js
$('.js-slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  autoplay: false
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 5rem auto 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.item {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.card {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  Section
  <div class="container__slider js-slider">
      <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2>Subheader</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2>Subheader</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2>Subheader</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Display: flex и height: 100%

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 5rem auto 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.container__slider {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  padding: 0 10px;
  flex: 1 0 0px;
}

.card {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  Section
  <div class="container__slider js-slider">
      <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2>Subheader</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2>Subheader</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2>Subheader</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без jQuery. Воспользуйтесь свойствами `display: flex` и `align-items: stretch`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 5rem auto 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.container__slider {
  display: flex; // Вместо jQuery выстраивает контейнеры по горизонтали
}
.item {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid plum;
  display: flex; // Задаём display flex, чтобы можно было применить свойство stretch
  align-items: stretch; // Растягиваем авнутренние блоки по высоте
}
.card {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Section
<div class="container__slider js-slider">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2>Subheader</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2>Subheader</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="item">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2>Subheader</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если jQuery необходим, то скрипт карусели добавляет свои стили, тогда используйте свойство `height: 100%`.
У меня работает вот так:

```js
$('.js-slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  autoplay: false
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 5rem auto 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.container__slider {
  border: 1px solid coral;
}

.item {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid plum;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  Section
  <div class="container__slider js-slider">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="card">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Subheader</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="card">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="card">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Subheader</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="card">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="card">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Subheader</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```